# How do you add labels to your icloud/iphone calendar?

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, ical

I see how to add a label (i.e. home, work, etc.) for iCal events on a Mac, but how do you add labels via your iCloud account or on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

These aren't labels, they're separate calendars.

1. In the Calendar app on iPhone, choose Calendars at the bottom, then choose Add Calendar.
2. Enter a calendar name and choose a colour, then tap Done.
3. Move events to this calendar by selecting an event, choosing Calendar and setting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new "Calendars" in iCal to organize your events by color and show/hide Calendars as needed.

---

**iCloud.com**: Open "Calendar" App, Click "Edit" (bottom left), Click "+" to add a new Calendar.

**iPhone**: Open "Calendar" App, Click "Calendars" (bottom middle), Click "Add Calendar" to add a new Calendar.

You will be able to give a name and color of your choosing to the Calendar!

---

**Move Event to Another Calendar**: Open the event, click "Calendar", select new Calendar.